# What was the mass flow rate of the Titan IIIE stage 1 during the voyager 1 launch

Tags: rockets, voyager

I am doing a project and I cant seem to find an exact value for the mean mass flow rate of the Titan IIIE booster during stage one of the voyager 1 launch?

Comment: By definition, mass flow rate is thrust divided by specific impulse, so if you can find good sources for those values you can compute it.

Comment: What approximate values have you found?